# XamarinForms Shell navigation with TabBar items of previous page

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]I need to create a "detail" page that when I clicked from my "master" page, on some button, it redirects me to that "detail" page with navigation bar which has back button.
Code for this is as follows:

```
protected async Task GoToPage(string route)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route);
}
```

Question is: how to preserve downtab from my previous master page, to show as well as on my detail page?

design is look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9JO9.png

I only have navigation bar.

In my AppShell.xaml I defined TabBar section for my "master" page ("master" page is first in my tabbar menu).
Should I create separate TabBar for my "detail" page and somehow to insert navigation bar?

Comment: So you want a back button when you navigate forward?

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes, I want a back button in my NavBar when I landing from my previous page to that one, as well as I want BottomTabs - they will be the same from previous page. I hope that you understood me.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Page to the MenuItem tab.

```
 <MenuItem Text="About"
        IconImageSource="info.png"
        Command="{Binding AboutPageCommand}" />
```

Background code.

```
 public ICommand AboutPageCommand => new Command(async () => await NavigateToAboytPageAsync());

 async Task NavigateToAboytPageAsync()
  {
     await  Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"aboutPage");
     Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
  }
```

Register the page in the App.xaml.cs

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("aboutPage", typeof(AboutPage));
```

Comment: and how to add MenuItem inside BackButtonBehavior tag? Like ```<Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior 
            IconOverride="picture_container.png" 
            Command="{Binding ProfileClickCommand}" />
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>```

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? I mean there is no need for a behavior!

Comment: Please see my edited post. I added an image Page1 -> Page2. Maybe you right, I dont need BackButtonBehavior if Im going with TabBar for Page1 and Page2. I tried to add another block of TabBar in AppShell, but I dont have backbutton, also I dont have a room to add MenuItem. Another concern fo me is when User clickcs "Learn" and then returns to Actiity, it keep showing Page2, instead of Page1..

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called **IsTabStop** you can set in the Tab tag which can preserve downtab from your previous master page:

> `IsTabStop`, of type bool, indicates whether a Tab is included in tab
>   navigation. Its default value is true, and when its value is false the
>   Tab is ignored by the tab-navigation infrastructure, irrespective if a
>   TabIndex is set.

You can set it to **false** at specific tab to keep downtab at that tab.

Code example:

```
<!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Master" Icon="tab_feed.png" IsTabStop="False">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Here is the document: [shell/tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#tab-class)